# PHP convert string to variable not working

Tags: php, laravel, controller

This is what i'm trying:

```
class CategoryController extends Controller{
public $productsOrders= [
    1=> 'product_order_number',
    2=> 'product_name',
    3=> 'product_name',
    4=> 'created_at'
];
public $categoriesOrders= [
    1=> 'category_order_number',
    2=> 'category_name',
    3=> 'category_name',
    4=> 'created_at'
];
public $orderDesc = [
    3, 4
];
public static function getOrder($type){
    $orderId=  request()->order;
    $curOrders = ${$type.'Orders'};
    return $curOrders[$orderId ?? 1] ?? $curOrders[1];
}
}
```

But when i test it using `CategoryController::getOrder('products')` I get back:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: productsOrders in CategoryController
```

Why is it happening? the scope is public. If i move those inside the function it works...

Comment: this is a notice, not an error. Maybe you should instantiate your variables in the class constructor

Comment: but it's a static method, so there is no constructor called @danielarend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getOrder` is a static method and you are trying to access in non-static variable this error happen. also `${$type.'Orders'}` is a local function variable it is not a class variable.

try this

```
class CategoryController extends Controller{
    public static $productsOrders= [
        1=> 'product_order_number',
        2=> 'product_name',
        3=> 'product_name',
        4=> 'created_at'
    ];
    public static $categoriesOrders= [
        1=> 'category_order_number',
        2=> 'category_name',
        3=> 'category_name',
        4=> 'created_at'
    ];
    public $orderDesc = [
         3, 4
    ];
    public static function getOrder($type){
         $orderId=  request()->order;
         $curOrders = self::${$type.'Orders'};
        return $curOrders[$orderId ?? 1] ?? $curOrders[1];
   }
}
```

now call it

```
CategoryController::getOrder('products')
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's because the method is `static`, but not the class attributes, you just need to add `static` to the declaration of the attrbutes

```
public static $productsOrder= [ ... ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `$curOrders = ${$type.'Orders'};` i.e $productsOrders variable in the class function that's why you are getting `PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: productsOrders in CategoryController`.

You need to use the php's `self` or `$this` keywords for accessing the class properties(functions/variables) within the class. 
Here are examples of usage of both these keywords:

```
1. self::$productsOrders;
2. $this->productsOrders;
```

Comment: $this? but the method is static no ?

Comment: @Berto99 - Right! You cannot use $this in the static methods. You can use $this when the method is not static. Here you need to access `productsOrders` with the self keyword.